# How can I get rid of space which of no use when content is less than height of div, while using overflow:auto

Tags: css, html, height, overflow

HTML CODE

```
 <p>overflow:auto</p>
 <div class="auto">This adds the scroll bar based on you content.Here only vertical scroll bar needed so that is added n visible</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
  div.auto 
 {
 background-color:#00FF00;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 overflow:auto;
 }
```

OUTPUT

[image]

When I change my HTML code to

CHANGED HTML CODE

```
<p>overflow:auto</p>
 <div class="auto">content less than div height </div>
```

my output will be

NEW OUTPUT

[image]

So I want to use overflow:auto property. So that after some minimum height scroll-bar will appear, but when content is less than height of div then I do not want to use whole height of div.height should be equal to content's height.Please help.

Comment: This is a good question for a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwag2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change `height: 100px;` to `max-height: 100px;` and it will be automatic below that to the height of the content.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  div.auto 
 {
 background-color:#00FF00;
 width:100px;
 max-height:100px;
 overflow:auto;
 }
```

ha realised that the height:auto is default anyway, so you can just remove height altogether.

Comment: I tried this already.No help. wont get scroll-bar at all.Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `max-height` instead of `height`.

http://tinker.io/bbf56/1